# xcode 7 Objective c Warning - Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7, warnings

After Updating XCODE 7, I'm getting this warning, I am trying to get rid of this but I can't find a proper solution:

```
CFRelease(CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL((CFURLRef)theURL, NULL));
```

Warning is:

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Comment: What is the problem?  The second parameter shouldn't be NULL.  It doesn't even make sense to call this method with a NULL parameter.

Comment: It makes even less sense to immediately release the result.  You call the method which does nothing and then do nothing with the non-result.  Just delete the code.

Comment: the code is from a library this comment is shown before the code
**// From: http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/CFProxySupportTool/listing1.html
 // Work around <rdar://problem/5530166>.  This dummy call to 
 // CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL initialise some state within CFNetwork 
 // that is required by CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript.**

Comment: and the library is **//
//  ASIHTTPRequest.m
//
//  Created by Ben Copsey on 04/10/2007.
//  Copyright 2007-2010 All-Seeing Interactive. All rights reserved.
//
//  A guide to the main features is available at:
//  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest
//
//  Portions are based on the ImageClient example from Apple:
//  See: http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/ImageClient/listing37.html** @Avi

Comment: I want to make sure deleting this code dosen't affect rest of the program and i started iOS only a week ago so am pretty new

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest has been unmaintained for many years.  Don't use it.  Period.

Comment: Deleting the code crashes my app on start **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException** @Avi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a hack to get rid of this warning

```
 NSDictionary *proxySettings = NSMakeCollectable([(NSDictionary *)CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings() autorelease]);
    CFRelease(CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL((CFURLRef)theURL, (CFDictionaryRef)proxySettings));
```